# Add value to Posted object in back end C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a such a question, is it possible to add a value to posted object in MVC

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID = 1", LastName, FirstMidName, EnrollmentDate")] Student student)
{
    try {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Students.Add(student);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Like ID = 1, which doesn't work, of course. I want to add additional information about model, before it starts form validation process.
I have options like `TryValidateModel(my updated model)`, but in this situation I'm validating my object two times, or other option is to add hidden type in front end. The reason I want to do this, because I have CRUD operations for my model, and the validation is varying upon each type of CRUD. For example during update it doesn't check if the value exists in the database etc.

I come up with to solution to use HTTP method names like HTTPPUT HTTPDELETE, for validation, it will be REST like solution. Thanks everyone for help.

Comment: Can't you just set the value in the first line of the method?  Or in the model's constructor?

Comment: the value is like CRUD identifier, for instance IsDelete property, which is true only when I call Delete action, I use ViewModel, and I don't want to use several models for doing that work

Comment: You can add additional values using route values but its not clear what your trying to do or what the purpose of the additional value is.

Comment: I don't want to use route values,, because route values can be changed from front end. Is it normal to use action name in the validation, or can I add some parameter to my action, which I can access from model validation? I was playing with modelstate yesterday, it adds another solution to my problem, but again I want something special :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching the Internet for answers, reading articles and books I come up with several solutions to my problem.
1. Adding a hidden type to my HTML and send it via Post method. The ViewModel validator uses the value of hidden type and does the validation as needed. But I don't like the idea of hidden types.
2. The second solution is using custom model binder, which can be advanced solution
3. Adding additional values to the route, this solution is the best one, Action name can help my model to understand what to validate.
4. There is another solution to add Modelstate modified, deleted properties,
 
But I'll use the 3-rd option, additionaly I think of using REST logic, and Validate depending HTTP method

Answer (score 1):

The best place to modify the input of ASP.net MVC Actions is the ModelBinder, create your custom generic ModelBinder and inherit from the default MVC `DefaultModelBinder` and add the information you want in the `BindModel` method override.

> Here is an example that can be extended to achieve what you want:

```
public class CustomModelBinderBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _extraProperties;

   public CustomModelBinderBinder(Dictionary<string, object> extraProperties)
   {
        _extraProperties = extraProperties;
   }

    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var model = bindingContext.Model;
        var modelType = model.GetType();
        var modelProperties = modelType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public);

        foreach (var property in _extraProperties)
        {
           var matchingProperty = modelType.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == property.Key);

            if (matchingProperty != null)
            {
                try
                {           
                    matchingProperty.SetValue(model, property.Value);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // what happens when we fail to set this value?
                    // possibly due to type mismatch, or readonly property
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In that example, the list of properties to extend comes in the constructor dynamic parameter, it is then used against the `Model` object to override or extend its properties.

Comment: Ok I'll try that option.

Comment: No Cutom Model Binder, will not help. I need the viewmodel to know for which operation it is validating. A field like Delete, Read, Put, must be sent to my validation code. I think now using data annotations for passing such field with value.